# .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found

Tags: openid

For some reason, I have started to receive  .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found. Although, the same configuration was working fine yesterday. May I know the reason why this may be happening?

This is my configuration:

```
                    var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions
                    {
                        Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
                        ClientId = externalProvider.ClientId,
                        UseTokenLifetime = true,
                        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

                        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = false
                        }
                    };
```

Please note I have already verified that my redirect_url is correctly configured.

---

Well for those who have the same problem please note that I had added two OpenId Connect configurations in my project which lead to this error. To resolve this error, you must provide unique CallbackPath to each of those configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned above, the error is caused when you have more than one OpenId configurations in your project. To solve this error, you must provide a unique CallbackPath to each of those configurations.